# XAML window shows image blurred

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new in WPF and I'm trying to show an image in a WPF windows, and then show a button, and two links in a absulute coordinate. I have two problems:

1. The floating controls are moved from one computer to other
2. The image is blurred. I think that is being resized.

The form must be a fixed dialog, and the image size is 800x560.

Here is my code:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="A.B.C.IntroGuideWindow"
        Title="Intro guide" Icon="../Resources/app_icon.ico"
        Background="{DynamicResource DialogBackgroundBrush}" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Style="{DynamicResource WindowStyle}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" Width="830" Height="660">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionaries/Colors.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionaries/BasicStyles/StandardWindowStyle.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionaries/ButtonStyles/ActionFlatButtonStyle.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionaries/ButtonStyles/CancelButtonStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="22"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Margin="10,10,10,10" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="21"
            FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="{DynamicResource FontBrush}" Grid.Row="0">
            <Run Text="Intro guide" />
        </TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="closeButton" Style="{DynamicResource CloseChromeButtonStyle}"
            Click="CancelButton_Click" Grid.Row="0"
            Content="r" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,6,0" FontFamily="Webdings" IsTabStop="False" />
        <Image x:Name="CurrentImage" Grid.Row="1" Width="800" Height="560" Stretch="None" Source="Images/sm-eval-guide-09.png" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        <Button x:Name="OpenSamplesButton" Content="Click here to open the samples directory" IsDefault="False"
            Style="{DynamicResource ActionFlatButtonStyle}"
            Margin="256,115,265,434" Width="301" Height="23" Click="OpenSamplesButton_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="DocumentationLink" Margin="2,221,-2,333" Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Hyperlink Foreground="#00A586" NavigateUri="http://www.example.com/#documentation">http://www.example.com/#documentation</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TwitterLink" Margin="590,415,84,137" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Hyperlink Foreground="#00A586" NavigateUri="https://twitter.com/xxx">@xxx</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2">
            <Button x:Name="PreviousButton" Content="Previous" IsDefault="False"
                Style="{DynamicResource ActionFlatButtonStyle}"
                Margin="0,0,200,10" Width="90" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="PreviousButton_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="NextButton" Content="Next" IsDefault="True"
                Style="{DynamicResource ActionFlatButtonStyle}"
                Margin="0,0,105,10" Width="90" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="NextButton_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Content="Close" IsDefault="False"
                Style="{DynamicResource ActionFlatButtonStyle}"
                Margin="0,0,10,10" Width="90"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="CloseButton_Click"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="DontShowAgainCheckbox" Content="Don't show this window again." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="DontShowAgainCheckbox_Checked"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. WPF adjusts for pixel density of the monitor it is running on. Consider using Grid Columns  or other layout controls such as `StackPanel` instead of Margin offsets. For example, your buttons could use the following layout:

   ```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
       <Button x:Name="PreviousButton" Content="Previous" IsDefault="False"
           Style="{DynamicResource ActionFlatButtonStyle}" Margin="4,0"
           Width="90" Click="PreviousButton_Click"/>
       <Button x:Name="NextButton" Content="Next" IsDefault="True"
           Style="{DynamicResource ActionFlatButtonStyle}" Margin="4,0"
           Width="90" Click="NextButton_Click"/>
       <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Content="Close" IsDefault="False"
           Style="{DynamicResource ActionFlatButtonStyle}" Margin="4,0"
           Width="90" Click="CloseButton_Click"/>
   </StackPanel>
   ```
2. For the blurred image, try using `UseLayoutRounding="False"` in your `Image` definition.